# Is the following statement is True/false ? ..

Tags: real-analysis

Is the  following  statement is True/false ?

Given that  $f_n(x) =(-x)^n $ , $x \in [0,1] $ then  $f_n$  converges pointwise everywhere ?

i thinks it will be  true  same  as  $f(x)  =  0 $ when x =0 ,$f(x) =1$  when

$0 <x \le 1$

Am i right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** correct. If you define $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\in[0,1)\\1&x=1\end{cases}$$

then $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $[0,1)$, however, for $x=1$, the sequence $f_n(x)$ becomes $(-1)^n$ which is the sequence $1,-1,1,-1,\dots$, a sequence that does **not** converge.

Comment: @%xum but im confusing at negative sign  $(-x)^n = x^n$

Comment: @jasmine Oh, I missed the negative sign! Sorry, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct except for when $x=1$. When $x=1$ you get a sequence $f_n = (-1)^n$ which does not converge, and therefore does not converge pointwise at that point.